# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with memset in char pointer in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memset

I have two version of code. One works and the other doesnot.

Working code is a follows :

```
 int main()
    {
        int i;
        char str[] = "Hello World";
        std::cout<<"The string value before memset is : "<<str<<std::endl;
        memset (str,'-',6);
        std::cout<<"The string value after memset is : "<<str<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

It gives expected output :

```
The string value before memset is : Hello World
The string value after memset is : ------World
```

Now, I have another version of code in which I want to use the char pointer but this code is not working. I get the following output :

```
int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = "Hello World";
    std::cout<<"The string value before memset is : "<<str<<std::endl;
    memset (str,'-',6);
    std::cout<<"The string value after memset is : "<<str<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
The string value before memset is : Hello World
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I just could not figure on what is happening. Could you help me on this?

Comment: "I have another version of code" - show us!

Comment: lol - you show the code that works, but not the code that fails!

Comment: i know what it says tho - it says `char *str = "Hello World"`

Comment: String literals are *constant*. You can not and should not modify them. That's why you should always use `const char*` when declaring pointers to them.

Comment: my strings are republicans not liberals

Comment: @pm100 I have *liberated* them! ;)

Comment: @pm100 I have added the non working code

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If I use const char* then it gives me error :
error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: @enjal That's because you're not supposed to modify the data! A literal string pointed to by a pointer, is *constant*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What compiler are you using?  That should not compile, because "Hello World" is a const char[12], which decays to const char*.  In C++ it's not valid to assign a const char* to a char*, because you cannot lose const without a cast.  Modifying const data is undefined behavior, so a crash is reasonable.  (Usually string literals are placed in a read-only memory segment so it will likely crash if you write to them (but that's a compiler detail, not language.))

If you want to modify the data, you must copy the string literal into your own memory.  Your first is a valid way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have

```
char *str = "Hello world";
```

in your failing code. The `memset` fails because `str` is a pointer to a constant string. You are not allowed to change constant strings.

In the one that works

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
```

copies the constant string into a local variable. You are allowed to change that.

Comment: I have to work in the pointer version.

Comment: @enjal : Then "Yousa screwed," quoth the Gungan. You can't write into constant memory without invoking the bad-weirds of undefined behaviour.

Comment: what you mean 'i have to work with the pointer one'?